# DWM messages constant values

Tags: c#, int, constants, message, dwm

I searched on internet, but I couldnt find what I am intersted in...

I am trying to find the value of

```
private const int DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't find it because the real name is WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED.  You find it by searching through the files in the Windows SDK's Include directory on your machine.

You'd find WinUser.h, the value is 0x31e.